# FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() reliability

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As I read from documentation and other sources it is advised to call **FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();** inside **onTokenRefresh()** to make sure that we get the updated token

what I tried was to call it every time the app is opened and its returning value always, and I am wondering is that a thing to trust ?(**is it guaranteed to generate the token every time its called?** ) or is there any case it might return null ?

since I don't want users logged in to multiple devices with the same account I am hoping to use it as unique identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my knowledge and experience I will try to resolve your doubts:

> Is it guaranteed to generate the token every time its called?

No it will not generate token every time you call this method. It will just return current token.

> Is there any case it might return null ?

Yes it returns null if your token is not yet generated.

> I am hoping to use it as unique identifier

Yes you can use it as a unique identifier for each device not for each account. Every device has its unique token.

This is from the official doc:

> Retrieve the current registration token
>
> When you need to retrieve the current token, call
>   FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(). This method returns null
>   if the token has not yet been generated.

For more information refer [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer almost most of my questions are answered but to clear the idea, after the token is generated calling **FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();** does return current token always right ?

Comment: Yes it always returns current token.